# Caroufredsel - Passing additional parameters in callback methods

Tags: jquery, caroufredsel

With the plugin 'Caroufredsel' you can setup callback events for when certain things change, for example when a different slide is visible.

```
options.scroll.onAfter(data) {
    console.log(data);
};
```

I want to pass an additional parameter but I'm not sure how to do it. For example, if I do

```
var foo = 'bar';
options.scroll.onAfter(data,foo) {
    console.log(foo);
};
```

Then foo is undefined. I expect that this is down to the plugin architecture not accepting additional arguments?

Is there a way around this? I tried setting up an event listener:

```
$el.on('onAfter', {foo: bar}, function() {
    console.log(e.data.foo);
});
```

But unfortunately it doesn't appear as though the plugin fires the events.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use a global variable ? Like that :

```
var state = 'foo';

options.scroll.onAfter(data) {
    console.log(state);
    state = 'bar';
};
```

Comment: I don't think it'd work as the whole thing is within an object. Foo is actually the instance of the object that I'm trying to pass, so once the event happens I can still run object methods from that callback.